# MySQL, which is more efficient longtext, text, or blob? Improving insert efficiency

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal, mysqli

I am in the process of migrating a large amount of data from several databases into one. As an intermediary step I am copying the data to a file for each data type and source db and then copying it into a large table in my new database.

The structure is simple in the new table, called migrate_data. It consists of an id (primary key), a type_id (incremented within the data type set), data (a field containing a serialized PHP object holding the data I am migrating), source_db (refers to the source database, obviously), data_type (identifies what type of data we are looking at).

I have created keys and key combinations for everything but the data field. Currently I have the data field set as a longtext column. User inserts are taking about 4.8 seconds each on average. I was able to trim that down to 4.3 seconds using DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 on the table.

What I want to know about is whether or not there is a way to improve the performance even more. Possibly by changing to a different data column type. That is why I ask about the longtext vs text vs blob. Are any of those more efficient for this sort of insert?

Before you answer, let me give you a little more information. I send all of the data to an insert function that takes the object, runs it through serialize, then runs the data insert. It is also being done using Drupal 6 (and its db_query function).

Any efficiency improvements would be awesome.

**Current table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `migrate_data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `data` longtext NOT NULL,
  `source_db` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `data_type` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `migrated_data_source` (`source_db`),
  KEY `migrated_data_type_id` (`type_id`),
  KEY `migrated_data_data_type` (`data_type`),
  KEY `migrated_data_id__source` (`id`,`source_db`),
  KEY `migrated_data_type_id__source` (`type_id`,`source_db`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The various text/blob types are all identical in storage requirements in PHP, and perform exactly the same way, except text fields are subject to character set conversion. blob fields are not. In other words, blobs are for when you're storing binary that MUST come out exactly the same as it went in. Text fields are for storing text data that may/can/will be converted from one charset to another.

Comment: Ok, well is there any other way to improve insert speeds?

Comment: Not really, unless you cut back on how much data you're writing. Storing the data externally and only storing file paths/metadata in the DB would be more efficient.

Comment: Really??? I would figure that storing it in files would be more expensive. Especially since I have to migrate the data in batches and I have to manipulate the data that I am importing before inserting it into Drupal. The problem I am seeing is that the system is running out of memory sometimes and if that doesn't happen then a random Drupal function will time out. So far none of my functions have timed out. But by using the database I figure that I am eliminating some resource usage by putting it in the DB.

Comment: think about it: to put the file into the db, it's got to be read off disk, coerced into MySQL's wire format, sent over the wire (even if it's a local socket), decoded, then written out to disk yet again inside mysql's innodb/whatever files. This, as opposed to just moving the file somewhere on the drive and inserting a few bits of metadata.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Well then the only benefit gained by using the db structure for intermediary storage would be the searching abilities and the fact that the MySQL server processes would run separately from the Apache/PHP processes. Thus giving more breathing room within the allowed resources for those particular processes. So your basically offloading some responsibilities to the MySQL server processes.

Comment: you can't really do much in the way of searching on blob/text fields anyways. They can't be indexed (beyond a few Kbytes at the start of the field), and retrieval becomes problematic if the blob size exceeds the server's max_allowed_packet setting.

Comment: @pthurmond, I know this is old, but your comment requires a response.  Storing raw data in the MySQL database is never beneficial for performance, I've only seen the contrary.  The web-server must still serve the data, and must now get it over the socket.  The only tangible benefit, when saving such data to MySQL database, would be an easier restore procedure.  However even this often comes at a steeper cost, longer MySQL backups and possibly slightly slower queries.